# how to find the x y origins of UIButton in Xcode

Tags: xcode, uibutton

So I have a `UIButton` which I need to replace with a better method but I have carefully positioned it using storyboard so I would like to know how to find the x y origins NON-programatically how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Option A**

Get the coordinates in Interface Builder:

1. Tap on the `UIButton` in your XIB file, to select it.
2. Tap on the Ruler in the upper-right-hand corner, to select the Size Inspector
3. The `View` panel at the top shows the X and Y coordinates, with the width and height underneath.

[image]
[image]

**Option B**

Here is an application that you can install on your Mac, to get the coordinates of anything on your desktop. The application overlays a vertical and horizontal ruler on your desktop, showing coordinates of the mouse as you move it. I find it very convenient:

http://www.pascal.com/software/freeruler/

You can align the upper-left-hand corner of the ruler with that of the view's origin in Interface Builder, to show the coordinates of that view.